# How to call a function from $rootScope

Tags: angularjs

I need to call an Angular function on the hidden event of a bootstrap modal.

Here is my hidden event handler:

```
    $('#modalAddAction').on('hidden.bs.modal',
        function (e) {
            console.log("in hidden.bs.modal");
            var $rootScope = angular.element(document.querySelector("[ng-controller=actionsController]")).scope();
            if ($rootScope) {
                $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                    $rootScope.initializeAt1();
                });
            }
        });
```

Here is the function defined in the controller I need to call:

```
       $scope.initializeAt1 = function () {
            $scope.data.addAction.actionTypeId; // initialized in $scope.getActionTypes
            $scope.data.addAction.actionStatus = 1;
            // initializers help set drop downs to appropriate selection.
            $scope.data.addAction.actionType1.actionRecommendedByLerId = 0;
            $scope.data.addAction.actionType1.actionsRecommendedByLer = [];
            $scope.data.addAction.actionType1.actionProposedBySupervisorId = 0;
            $scope.data.addAction.actionType1.actionTakenBySupervisorId = 0;
            $scope.data.addAction.actionType1.actionChargeId = 0; // formerly initialized in $scope.getActionCharges
            $scope.data.addAction.actionType1.actionCharges = [];
        }();
```

So the first time the controller factory is run, the initializeAt1 function calls itself and does the initialization I need.

Then I try to call initializeAt1 again whenever the modal is hidden, whether from a save buttion, a cancel button, or just clicking on the screen.

The #modalAddAction - hidden event here gives me this error:

```
[$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress
```

So now I try to change he event handler to this (comment out the apply and just directly call the function from $rootScope):

```
    $('#modalAddAction').on('hidden.bs.modal',
        function (e) {
            console.log("in hidden.bs.modal");
            var $rootScope = angular.element(document.querySelector("[ng-controller=actionsController]")).scope();
            //if ($rootScope) {
                //$rootScope.$apply(function () {
                    $rootScope.initializeAt1();
                //});
            //}
        });
```

And now I get this error.

```
$rootScope.initializeAt1 is not a function
```

So I have the rootScope, but why does it not see the function?

Comment: hi i think the problem is you're doing var $rootScope .. you're re-assign the $rootScope with new object ..it make no sense

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.
It just didn't like the function being self called after the definition.
When I inspected the $scope off of the $rootScope initailizeAt1 was listed as undefined.

Had to take () off of the end.

And add the call:

```
        $scope.initializeActions = function () {
            $scope.initializeAt1();
        }
        $scope.initializeActions();
```

at the end.

Will then add init for At2, At3 and so on to initializeActions.